# Unable to trigger tablesorter in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, tablesorter

I trying to remove a row in tablesorter from iframe  and i am successfully able to remove but i am not able to trigger update tablesorter here is what i am trying

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var uid = ". json_encode($_POST['uid']) . ";
    var access = " . json_encode($_POST['access']) . ";
    if(access == '1') {
     top.$('#content').contents().find('#orgs tr[data-uid='+uid+']').remove();
      top.$('#content').contents().find('#orgs').trigger('update');
      console.log(top.$('#content').contents().find('#orgs'));
    }
    top.$.fancybox.close();
});
```

i couldn't understand if i am able to remove a row and also in console.log it shows, but why not trigger update but i try to trigger in same iframe with this `$('#orgs').trigger('update');` then it work

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery's `.contents()` when accessing the parent window:

```
if (access == '1') {
  top.$('#content').find('#orgs tr[data-uid='+uid+']').remove();
  top.$('#content').find('#orgs').trigger('update');
  console.log(top.$('#content').find('#orgs'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But No it doesn't work, in this way it doesn't even remove row

Comment: Does the `console` return anything? I tested a similar code locally (in Firefox) and it was working for me.

Comment: in console it returns object with length 0, there is no error at all but it does not remove row, Just for more clarity i telling that i  call this edit page in fancybox on click of row if it does matter